# How to delete static-html cache files that are owned by Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I have set up page caching that creates HTML files in the public folder on the fly. I am using Capistrano for deploying the Rails app.

The problem starts when you need to **clean up old releases** in Capistrano. The cache files are **owned by rails**, meaning the deploy user can't delete the files.

I do not have root permissions to the server, so using elevated privileges isn't an option.

One possibility that has been suggested is to symlink the cache into the **shared folder**. However, this won't clear the cache between releases, which could be dangerous.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sweepers you may look to sweepers on rails and write some to delete all the currents accordingly.

Comment: Right -- if rails can create the file, Rails can delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the main problem is that when you run a capistrano task, you have a user (usually the deploy user), so in order to create/delete files, your deploy user should have permissions on them.

So your web user (in this case rails) is not related to the deploy user and as you said, you don't cannot have root permissions on the server (probably a hosting company, right?)

You can create an action in your website, on where only you will have access, something like
http://mywebsite.com/clear_cache

And on that action, you actually write the code to list each one of the older deploys, and to clear the cache files inside the old deploys, by doing that, the user who will be deleting the files will be web user (rails).